Can a locally quadratic function be non-twice differentiable?
Fix $x_0$ and suppose $$f(x_0+h) = f(x_0)+c_1h+c_2h^2+o(h^2)\,,\quad h\to 0\,.$$
My hunch is that this does not imply anything about $f$, except at $x_0$. I am interested, therefore in an example where $f$ is not differentiable in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Of course, it may turn out that $f$ is in fact differentiable in a neighborhood of $x_0$ (or even stronger, that $f$ is twice differentiable at $x_0$), and needless to say, I would still be interested.

Your assumption does not give you any regularity condition other than differentiability in $x_0$. For instance, let $x_0=0$. Consider the function (defined on $\mathbb R$) $$f(x)=ax+bx^2+\begin{cases}0&\text{if $x$ is not in $\mathbb Q$;}\\x^3&\text{if $x\in\mathbb Q$.}\end{cases}$$ Then $f(x) = f(0)+ax+bx^2+o(x^2)$. However, it is discontinuous everywhere but in $0$.

A nitpick: If it is discontinuous everywhere but in $0$, then it cannot be twice differentiable.

@Andrew oh ofc you're right, this is not twice differentiable not even in 0 (the first derivative must exist there though). Well spotted! I'll fix the answer.
